# How to specify pch by the value of a variable?

Tags: r, pch

I'm making a plot of Y vs X for some discrete points in R. There is a third variable Z that has a value of either A or B, so I want to identify the third variable by pch in the plot. I can do the following.

```
plot(X, Y, pch=c(3,4)[Z])
```

However, I don't know whether Z=="A" is assigned to 3 or 4 in this case. How do I specify that Z=="A" is plotted as 4 and that Z=="B" is plotted as 3?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset from `c(3, 4)` based on value of `Z` like :

```
c(3,4)[(Z == "A") + 1]
```

so when `Z <- "A"`

```
Z <- "A"
c(3,4)[(Z == "A") + 1]
#[1] 4
```

and when `Z <- "B"`

```
Z <- "B"
c(3,4)[(Z == "A") + 1]
#[1] 3
```

So the code would be

```
plot(X, Y, pch = c(3,4)[(Z == "A") + 1])
```

---

Another option is to use `ifelse`

```
plot(X, Y, pch = ifelse(Z == "A", 4, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The first option works. However, the second option gives an error: “the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used”.

Comment: @S.J. If you have multiple value for `Z` you need `ifelse`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Or a subset from a named vector - `plot(df$x, df$y, pch=c("B"=3,"A"=4,"C"=5)[as.character(df$z)])`

Answer (score 2):

You could factor your Z column. For example:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:12, y = 12:1, z = c('A','B','C'))

df$z = as.factor(df$z)

plot(df$x, df$y, pch = c(22,23,24)[df$z])
```

will give you:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to plot X and Y first,

```
plot(X, Y)
```

After that, plot Z on the same plot using points(). Do it separately based on different `pch`.

```
points(X, Z[Z == "A"], pch = 4)
points(X, Z[Z == "B"], pch = 3)
```